# Rails: Form in partial for new nested ressource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I try to create a new message for a conversation via a form.

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages
```

So far I'm using a partial to create new messages _new_message.html.erb:

```
<div id="message_dialog">
  <%= simple_form_for [:front, @conversation] do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :challenge_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @conversation.challenge.id } %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :messages do |m| %>
      <%= m.input :subject %>
      <%= m.input :text, as: :text %>
      <%= m.input :recipient_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: @conversation.challenge.user_id } %>
      <%= m.input :sender_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: current_user.id } %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

In the ConversationsController's show action I define:

```
@conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
@conversation.messages.build
```

This works for creating a new message for a new conversation.

However, when I try to create a new message for a conversation which already has other messages the form helper creates an edit field **for every message which belongs to the conversation**

What is the best way to create a new nested ressource?

**Preferrably, I'd like to use the same partial to create a new message for a new conversation and a new message for an existing conversation which already has other messages**.

Comment: Post your `new` controller code so I can understand your setup better

Comment: You can call that partial in `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` and in controller you can set `@conversation` accordingly.

Comment: @WesFoster I don't have a message#new controller, as I want to append the form for a new message to the bottom of the conversation#show action.

Comment: Can you post your `conversations_controller`?

Comment: Sounds like `@conversation` is assigned to an existing record

Comment: yes @JonathanAllard conversation is an existing resource and I want to add a new message resource to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours I found the answer.

simple_fields_for can have either one or two arguments.

With one argument

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :messages do |g| %>
```

the form helper creates input fields for all the messages of the conversation.

With two arguments

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :messages, @conversation.messages.build do |f| %>
```

the form helper creates input fields only for the new message I want to create. This means we specify the object name and the object itself independently here according to this [source](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

Ach, and don't forget to whitelist the the nested params:

```
def conversation_params
  params.require(:conversation).permit(..., messages_params: [:subject, ...])
end
```

Comment: (`@message = `) `@conversation.messages.build` needs to be in the controller.